# What is meant by projection of this basket? What will the breadth of the basket containing fruits?

Tags: area, parameter-estimation, projection, measurement-theory

It is mentioned that the diameter of the basket is 13" and the projection is 10"
I am clear with the diameter can someone please explain what is mentioned by the projection here?

Also, what would be the depth and breadth of the lower part of the basket?[image]

Here is the link to basket https://www.anthropologie.com/shop/hanging-loretta-basket?recommendation=pdp-rightRail-sfrectray-pdprightrailsimilaritems&_gl=1%2adxw0lw%2a_up%2aMQ..&quantity=1&epik=dj0yJnU9R1R5V0JGbVp6M0lBQnpHaC1UbkN2UVBHeEtZeVMzQ2EmcD0wJm49Q0VYUkRTQzVQMi1CcWtBREZoSUdqZyZ0PUFBQUFBR094UmxR

Comment: An approximation of this shape can be done by a (part of) a [Dupin cyclide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dupin_cyclide)

Comment: This is not a mathematical question. I'm not complaining - it is obvious why you would mistake it as being such - but the "projection" they are referring to is not some mathematical operation. My guess it refers to how far the basket "projects" out from the wall. I.e., the distance from the furthest part of the basket to the wall is 10 inches.